# Pushing from mercurial project to the svn project

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, repository

I'm working on a project that uses svn, but I like the way mercurial works. I can't force the other folks to use mercurial and convert the whole project, so I decided to use mercurial just locally. Thus the situation is like this: I have a directory containing the svn copy of the remote repository, and another directory in which I work locally, under mercurial version control. The thing I'd like to do is to create a new repository in the directory containing the svn copy (and I've done it yet) and to push my changes from my local working directory to this new repository and pull changes from it.

This way I can avoid to copy manually each time my updates and merge manually, which is really a pain...

I've tried to do

```
hg push path/to/hg/repo/in/svn/folder
```

but I receive an error message like:

```
abort: the repository isn't related
```

(I'm not sure about this, the error message is in italian, and I'm not sure about the correct translation) and an exit code of 255 (on Debian GNU/Linux).

I hope I've explained quite clearly my problem, thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hg push --svn` after `hg pull` and `hg rebase`. See [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) for details.